# Best way to make many boolean selections

Tags: website-design, gui-design, input, select

[image: multi image selection]

I'm making a tool that crops images at various sizes. Currently, I use checkboxes to show the different sizes, but this will grow unwieldy when I add more crop sizes.

What's the best way to show all the available options?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are users allowed to select multiple choices like shown in the image or is that just for demonstration?

Comment: They can select multiple choices, like in the image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, checkboxes are difficult to use when there are many due to their size. In this case, I'm not sure checkboxes is the right UI element. You're asking people to select *products*, not options (which is what checkbox is mostly for).

I think the solution is presented right in your screenshot. List all your products in a grid and let user select them on click. To make this option discoverable highlight the product on rollover and display a checkmark once it's selected. Something like this:
[image]

Comment: @SamuelHill Does it deserve an upvote :)?

Comment: At least one!   :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with combinatorial explosion for various widths and heights.  Can you have the user select width in one step and then select availble heights (that go with the selected width) in a separate step?